# Sitecore NextJS Build

Tags: next.js, sitecore

I have a *Sitecore* NextJS project and I have SSG enabled. What's the best way to test this out?
Do I just run the next build command and will it generate the static html files?
Is that how this works? Is there some documentation out there explaining this end-to-end?